# Error " 'Softmax' object has no attribute 'log_softmax' " while training Neural Network with PyTorch

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am working on a classifier for MNIST dataset. When I am running the code below, I am getting the error " 'Softmax' object has no attribute 'log_softmax' " at line `loss = loss_function(output, y)`. I have not managed to find a solution to the problem. I will appreciate if you can advise on how the issue can be resolved. Thank you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch 
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F 
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset, TensorDataset
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import numpy as np


device = torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")
batch_size = 512

# Image transformations of Torchvision will convert to the images to tensor and normalise with mean and standard deviation
transformer = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize(mean=(0.1307,), std=(0.3081,))])

data_train = DataLoader(torchvision.datasets.MNIST('Data/data/mnist', download=True, train=True, transform=transformer), 
                batch_size=batch_size, drop_last=False, shuffle=True)
data_test = DataLoader(torchvision.datasets.MNIST('Data/data/mnist', download=True, train=False, transform=transformer), 
                batch_size=batch_size, drop_last=False, shuffle=True)


class neural_nw(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(neural_nw, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(784, 128, True)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 128, True)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(128, 10, True)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        output = torch.sigmoid(self.fc1(x))
        output = torch.sigmoid(self.fc2(output))
        output = nn.Softmax(self.fc3(output))
        return output
    
MLP = neural_nw()

loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimiser = optim.Adam(MLP.parameters(), lr = 0.01)

Epochs = 50

for epoch in range(Epochs):
    for X, y in data_train:
        X = X.view(X.shape[0], -1)
        optimiser.zero_grad()
        output = MLP.forward(X)
        loss = loss_function(output, y)
        loss.backward()
        optimiser.step()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nn.Softmax` defines a module, `nn.Modules` are defined as Python classes and have attributes, e.g., a `nn.LSTM` module will have some internal attributes like `self.hidden_size`. On the other hand, `F.softmax` defines the operation and needs all arguments to be passed (including the weights and bias). Implicitly, the modules will usually call their *functional* counterpart somewhere in the `forward` method.

This explains why `F.softmax` instead of `nn.Softmax` resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `output = nn.Softmax(self.fc3(output))` with `output = F.softmax(self.fc3(output))` seems to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your `nn.softmax` to `F.softmax` why? because the nn.functional contains the softmax operation, and you have imported it already in our code `torch.nn.functional as F`. So to solve the problem, just make it `F.softmax` instead of `nn.softmax`.